# How to make a dropdown for every FlatList item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Kind of surprised at the lack of information I can find about this question, feel like its something that you be done pretty often? I know with a standard dropdown it's pretty easy, you set up a hook that controls state with a boolean, when that boolean is true, you show the dropdown, when it's false, you show the closed version.

The Issue that I discovered when trying to do this with each render item is that the hook state control needs to be in the global context, because of this whenever you click on Flatlist item, all of the items open because they are all using the same state control. How would you make it so that each rendered item has its own dropdown state when you can't set a state hook inside each render item?

Here's my code to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about, be sure to read the comments:

```
<FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10, minHeight: 200 }}
                    data={notes}

                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
                    ListFooterComponent={() => <AddNoteFooter onPress={addSpecificNote} />}

                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        //would need something similar to a hook right here,
                        // to manage the state of each item individually

                        //change "isOpen" state when button is pressed
                        return (
                            <View>
                                {!isOpen &&
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={null} style={styles.flastliststyle}>
                                        <Text style={styles.flastlistItemText}>{item.note}</Text>


                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                }
                                {isOpen &&
                                    <TouchableOpacity>
                                    /* extended dropdown code */
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                }
                            </View>)
                    }
```

Looking to do something similar to this video but where each item is a flatlist item (also using hooks):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awEP-pM0nYw&t=134s

Thank you!

SOLUTION:

flatlist:

```
<FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10, minHeight: 200 }}
                    data={notes}

                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
                    ListFooterComponent={() => <AddNoteFooter onPress={addSpecificNote} />}

                    renderItem={({ item }) => {

                        return (
                            <NoteItem noteitem={item} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
```

then the component rendered for each item:

```
const NoteItem = (props) => {

    const [isOpen, updateDrop] = useState(false)


    return (
        <View>
            {!isOpen &&
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateDrop(prev => !prev)} style={styles.flastliststyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.flastlistItemText}>{props.noteitem.note}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
            {isOpen &&
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateDrop(prev => !prev)} style={styles.flastliststyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.flastlistItemText}>pressed</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        </View>
    )

}
```

Comment: If anyone comes across this problem or something similar it was actually pretty easy. Took way to long for me to figure out but I ended up making each item its own component, this way the hook can be at the base level of the component file. Check edits for the solutions code :)